# When to use "in" vs "window."

Tags: javascript

More speceifcally

```
if("indexedDB" in window)
```

vs

```
if(window.indexedDB)
```

I always use the second method but in the [net tuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/working-with-indexeddb/) they are using method 1.

Comment: they actually use `if("indexedDB" in window)` (*quoted property name*) but the question stands..

Answer (score 6):

`'indexedDB' in window` (note you need quotes) checks if the window has a property named `indexedDB` (without quotes, it's "a property with the name stored in the `indexedDB` variable")

`window.indexedDB` checks if the property with that name is truthy.

Now, in many cases, especially with feature testing, you already know that you are looking for an object, so it makes no difference which method you use. However in a more general situation:

```
window.derp = false;
if( 'derp' in window) { /* true */ }
if( window.derp) { /* false */ }
```

Comment: I was getting confused with _enumerability_ and `for..in` vs `in`. This answer is correct, +1, but you may also want to mention `.hasOwnProperty`. `o = {}; o.hasOwnProperty('toString') // false` vs `'toString' in o; // true`